# Resolve the linq expression error

Tags: c#, linq, generic-list

I've a code like given below, but it gives a compile error "Cannot convert expression type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to return type 'bool'

```
List<Condition> cod = MyRules.ToList().Where(r=>r.Conditions.ToList().Where(c=>c.id == 123).ToList();
```

Here I need to get all 'MyRules' which has conditions with 'id' = 123
Please help me to find out the correct way to right this expression. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, it's not clear why you're calling `ToList` all over the place. At the end, maybe... but no need for it any earlier. I think you're probably looking for the `Any` method:

```
List<Condition> cod = MyRules.Where(r => r.Conditions.Any(c => c.id == 123))
                             .ToList();
```

Note how writing one "top level" method call per line makes it easier to check brackets (your original code is missing at least one closing parenthesis) and easier to read in general.

If you want to find rules where *all* the conditions have an `id` of 123, you'd use `All` instead of `Any`.

Answer (score 1):

You have `ToList` call, inside `Where` clause:

```
      |                                               |
      ˅                                               ˅      
   Where(r=>r.Conditions.ToList().Where(c=>c.id == 123).ToList()
```

And don't use `ToList()` everywhere. If your types are enumerable, you do not need to convert them to `List<T>` to query them.

Comment: original question is missing parentheses, and so is your answer

Comment: @Joe I did it on purpose, so OP can locate error easily.

Comment: ok, I probably would have phrased that a little differently.  thanks